# Wikipedia API working intermittently with getJSON calls

Tags: javascript, html, wikipedia-api

I am having some trouble using the wikipedia api. I use .getJSON to return the data however it only works intermittently for some reason. I am not sure if there's a limit on the search that we can perform or something else. The page would just crash after a series of hit and misses.

I have clear all my cache stored in Chrome but the issue still persists. Please help, thank you.

```
function wiki_api(val) {


     $.getJSON("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?
     action=opensearch&search="+val+"&limit=5&format=json&callback=?", function(data) {

//console.log(search+"2");
console.log("runs")
console.log(data);
}); }


function ClickEvent() {
    var temp;
    console.log("before");
    var dummy = document.getElementById("test").value;
    var search = dummy.split(" ").join("+");
    console.log(search);

    wiki_api(search);
    console.log("ran");

   }
```

link to codepen: https://codepen.io/xguardx/pen/BwJMXx?editors=0011

Comment: "The page would just crash" Is that really what you mean? Like the browser tab crashes? If not, it would help if you would tell us what you actually see. Specifically, it would be interesting to know what the network traffic looks like in your browser.

Comment: The page just goes to the standard white html background page and I would have to reload.

Comment: Your codepen is using a submit button, it's reloading your page every time you click it.

Comment: Use `onsubmit="return ClickEvent();"` (not the `return`) and then add `return false;` to the end of `ClickEvent`.

Comment: This will prevent the form from doing it's normal submit after running the `onsubmit` handler. (@PatrickEvans has pointed out that this is the issue with your CodePen code.)

Comment: Thank you smarx, you have resolved the issue!